# How do I format a JSR-385 Quantity with fixed number of decimal digits?

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to convert hard-coded formatting to a [Java Units API](https://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/indriya/) implementation.

The existing code outputs (for this example, the temperature value in degrees) with two decimal places. For example, 38.70°C. While I'd like to allow the user to specify their own formatting code (which is [the end-goal](https://github.com/WestRidgeSystems/jmisb/issues/336) of the change), I think it would be useful to keep the legacy behavior to give people a chance to migrate.

The [existing code](https://github.com/WestRidgeSystems/jmisb/blob/2.x/api/src/main/java/org/jmisb/api/klv/st0809/AbstractTemperature.java#L47-L50) looks like:

```
        return String.format("%.2f\u00B0C", this.temperature);
```

The code I'm trying to use looks like:

```
        DecimalFormat numberFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        NumberDelimiterQuantityFormat formatter =
                NumberDelimiterQuantityFormat.builder()
                        .setNumberFormat(numberFormat)
                        .setDelimiter("")
                        .setUnitFormat(SimpleUnitFormat.getInstance())
                        .build();
        return formatter.format(temperature);
```

It does format, but not with the specified precision. I'd expect `38.70°C` but instead get `38.70000076293945℃`.

If I just do

```
numberFormat.format(temperature.getValue().floatValue());
```

then it does format correctly ("38.70"). So I think the DecimalFormat is basically OK.

I considered just manually building my formatting. However that doesn't really work for what I want to do - pass in the `NumberDelimiterQuantityFormat` (or applicable interface).

Can anyone suggest an appropriate way to format a `Quantity<>` with fixed decimal precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'm completely unfamiliar with the Java Unit API and this implementation, but this seemed like an interesting question, so I looked into it.

I had a look at the implementation of NumberDelimiterQuantityFormat and right there in the implementation of the `format` method it modifies the `maxiumFractionDigits` of the `NumberFormat` depending on the fraction

> ```
> if (quantity != null && quantity.getValue() != null) {
>     fract = getFractionDigitsCount(quantity.getValue().doubleValue());
> }
> if (fract > 1) {
>     numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(fract + 1);
> }
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/master/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/format/NumberDelimiterQuantityFormat.java#L279)

This makes little sense to me for two reasons:

1. It negates the whole reason to have a `NumberFormat` in the first place especially in context with floating point numbers where it's virtually impossible to avoid superfluous fraction digits.
2. It modifies the internal state of the `NumberDelimiterQuantityFormat` in a method where it isn't expected.

I should have checked first, but there is actually an [issue about this](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/issues/358), which is "being analyzed" for several months now. Maybe it would make sense to ask in there.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and pointer. Will ask on that issue.